# JNI: library loading design and Scala header file (.h) best practice

Tags: java, scala, gcc, java-native-interface

what is the best idea for the next:

i have a scala library that works on BSD(MacOS X, FreeBSD)/Linux/Windows via JNI function calls, and before i call some @native function, i'm need to load JNI lib, i.e. .so, .dylib, .dll

project structure:

/common (Scala code)

/windows (C code and Scala class binding)

/macos (C code and Scala class binding)

/linux (C code and Scala class binding)

current simplest solution (for MacOS X and if gcc installed):

```scala
(Process(s"cd c_native_path_src") ### Process(s"gcc -dynamiclib -O3 " +
    "-I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers " +
    "-I/usr/include " +
    "-I$JAVA_HOME/include " +
    s"-I$$JAVA_HOME/include/darwin" +
    s"$some_path/src/lib_native_util.c " +
    s"-o $some_path/$libPath/$libName$.dylib"))
```

what is the best solution? i've tried a CMake, but nothing worked, unfortunately

btw another question: if i have a header for Scala/Java class file that i already generated will it work on other platforms? for example, if i already generated a header for my Scala class(it was on BSD/MacOS) will it work on Windows/Linux when compiling C source code for @native functions?

Comment: I would suggest you some kind of [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) to help you. [Android Studio](https://developcom/er.android.studio) works on all your platforms and more...Supports JNI, Java, Scala, c++...

Comment: @JonGoodwin, please, can you explain to me how the IDE can help me?

I looked at Netty (because it also uses platform lib loading) and my goal is to develop a similar... 

https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/transport-native-kqueue/src/main/c
https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/transport-native-epoll/src/main/c

Comment: Netty doesn't call GCC, it provides appropriate binding

Comment: @cchantep hmmm, but what about compiling of native sources? If i got right, Netty already has an appropriate library?

How works my lib: I have a Scala class with native functions, and before i can call some of these funions, it's mandatory to load the library. 

What i'm doing: compiling C code (where JNI bingind) for creating a required shared library. Finally, i can use native functions, because when i loaded a library, lib file (.so, dylib, dll) is mmap-ed into the process address space.

Comment: The native code should be shipped in appropriate binary format (.so, .dylib, .dll), not as sources

Comment: @cchantep is it ok if an appropriate library for some platfrom is already in the source? i mean, if i'm working on Linux and my lib already has appropriate binary format (.so)? 

example: at path /linux/native/bin stored liblinux.so

Comment: There are mechanism to ship the binary native artifacts along with the JVM lib

Comment: @cchantep could you please show an example?

Comment: If you have a look at [netty native](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-transport-native-epoll/4.1.41.Final/), you will find it's shipped with a `.so` and check how it's loaded in the Java sources on GitHub project

Comment: @cchantep, okay, if it ok that native code shipped to appropriate bin format, i'll do the same. 

btw, could you please tell me will work on Mac/Windows my generated on Linux header file for Scala class?

Comment: Please have a look first how netty does it, as it as a kpoll lib specific to osx, that ships dylib